# ¿Por qué no me crea el fichero?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un programa que contiene dos métodos, uno guarda en un archivo de texto un arraylist con una serie de contactos y el otro carga los datos del arraylist en el programa.

El problema es que cuando defino el archivo

```
String ruta ="/home/miscompaneros/contactos.txt";
    File archivo = new File(ruta);
```

No me crea el archivo, ya que ejecuto la aplicacion y cuando debe cargar los datos guardados me aparece el siguiente error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/miscompaneros/contactos.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Si he creado mediante new el fichero, ¿porque pone que no existe?

Codigo completo:

```
package com.example.victor.miscompaneros;
```

public class editarcontacto  extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable{

```
 TextView campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6, campo7, campo8, advertencia1;

Integer telefono;
String nombre, papellido, sapellido, direccion, poblacion;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri imageUri;
ImageView foto_gallery;
Button boton1;
LocalDate fechanacimiento;
TableLayout lista;
static int contGlobal=0;



TableRow tabla2, tabla3, tabla4, tabla5, tabla6, tabla7, tabla8, tabla9;

int filas = 0, columnas = 0;

static ArrayList<Contacto> contactos = new ArrayList<Contacto>();

int i = 0;




@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editarcontacto);




    //se asigna el campo de texto a la id que deseamos
    campo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo1);
    campo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo2);
    campo3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo3);
    campo4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo4);
    campo5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo5);
    campo6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo6);
    campo7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campo7);
    campo8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    foto_gallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    boton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    lista = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.lista);


    //definimos las tablas

    tabla2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla2);
    /*tabla3= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla3);
    tabla4= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla4);
    tabla5= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla5);
    tabla6= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla6);
    tabla7= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla7);
    tabla8= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla8);
    tabla9= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tabla9);
    */




    advertencia1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    //if (contactos.size()>=1) {

        //cargardatosentabla();
    //}


    foto_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //Le llega la accion que debe tomar
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    int dato = extras.getInt("DATO");

    if (dato == 1) {
        campo8.setText("AÑADIR CONTACTO");
        boton1.setText("Añadir");

    }

}

/*private void cargardatosentabla() {

    TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    TextView textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);

    for (int cont=0;cont<contactos.size();cont++)
    {
        String n = contactos.get(i).getNombre();
        String apellido1 = contactos.get(i).getPapellido();
        String apellido2 = contactos.get(i).getSapellido();
        String apellidos = apellido1 + " " + apellido2;
        Integer telefono = contactos.get(i).getTelefono();
        String poblacion = contactos.get(i).getPoblacion();
        //LocalDate f = contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento();


        //añadimos los atributos a sus respectivo texto

        textview1.setText(n);
        textview2.setText(apellidos);
        textview3.setText(String.valueOf(telefono));
        textview4.setText(poblacion);
    }
}*/

public void metodo_iniciar(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), menucontactos.class);
    intent.putExtra("DATO", 1);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
public void metodo_editar2(View view) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    setContentView(R.layout.menucontactos);

    //fila1
    TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    TextView textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    //fila2
    TextView textview20 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
    TextView textview21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    TextView textview22 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    TextView textview23 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    //se añade el contacto

    nombre = campo1.getText().toString();
    papellido = campo2.getText().toString();
    sapellido = campo3.getText().toString();
    direccion = campo4.getText().toString();
    poblacion = campo6.getText().toString();
    try {
        telefono = Integer.parseInt(campo5.getText().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        advertencia1.setText("INTRODUZCA UN TELEFONO CORRECTO");
        advertencia1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    try {
        fechanacimiento = LocalDate.parse(campo7.getText().toString());


        //convertimos la fecha tipo date en local date
        //fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

        LocalDate fechaactual = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(fechaactual.getYear(), fechanacimiento.getMonthValue(), fechanacimiento.getDayOfMonth());
        if (fechaactual.isAfter(birthday))
            birthday = birthday.plusYears(1);
        Period diff = Period.between(fechaactual, birthday);
        Contacto contacto = new Contacto(nombre, papellido, sapellido, direccion, poblacion, R.drawable.agenda, telefono, fechanacimiento);

        contactos.add(contacto);


        // se añade el array a la tabla del menu superior


        do {


            String n = contactos.get(i).getNombre();
            String apellido1 = contactos.get(i).getPapellido();
            String apellido2 = contactos.get(i).getSapellido();
            String apellidos = apellido1 + " " + apellido2;
            Integer telefono = contactos.get(i).getTelefono();
            String poblacion = contactos.get(i).getPoblacion();
            //LocalDate f = contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento();


            //añadimos los atributos a sus respectivo texto
            switch(i) {
                case 0: textview1.setText(n);
                textview2.setText(apellidos);
                textview3.setText(String.valueOf(telefono));
                textview4.setText(poblacion);
                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

                case 1:
                    textview20.setText(n);
                    textview21.setText(apellidos);
                    textview22.setText(String.valueOf(telefono));
                    textview23.setText(poblacion);
                    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }

            //convertimos fecha en string para poder añadirla al texto
            //String fechatexto = contactos.get(i).convertirfecha(contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento());

            //textofecha.setText(fechatexto);

            //escribirDatosContactos();

            i++;

        } while (i < (contactos.size() - 1));

        //Guarda estado de actividad antes de cerrarla
        escribirDatosContactos();


    } catch (Exception e) {

        Logger.getLogger(editarcontacto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
        advertencia1.setText("INTRODUZCA UNA FECHA CORRECTA");
        advertencia1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    //cerramos esta actividad
    finish();

    //iniciamos la actividad desde menucontactos
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), menucontactos.class);
    intent.putExtra("DATO",1);
    startActivity(intent);

        leerFichContactos();


}


private void openGallery() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        foto_gallery.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
static void leerFichContactos() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    String ruta ="/home/miscompaneros/contactos.txt";
    File archivo = new File(ruta);


    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(archivo);
    ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    contactos = (ArrayList<Contacto>)objectIn.readObject();
    objectIn.close();

    ObjectInputStream leyendoFichero = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("ruta") );
    contactos = (ArrayList <Contacto> )leyendoFichero.readObject();
    leyendoFichero.close();


}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
static void escribirDatosContactos() throws IOException {


    String ruta ="/home/miscompaneros/contactos.txt";
    File archivo = new File(ruta);
    BufferedWriter bw;
    if(archivo.exists()) {
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(ruta);
        ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        out.writeObject(contactos);
        out.close();
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Tu método escribirDatosContactos() escribe algo al disco solo si el fichero existe. Si no existe, nunca lo crea.

Comment: ¿Y como creo el fichero?, porque yo pensaba que se creaba con File archivo = new File(ruta);

Comment: No confundas la clase `File` en java, que tiene la abstracción para manejar ficheros, con el fichero _físico_ en el disco. con `new File()` lo que haces es crear el objeto, pero eso no crea el archivo en disco. En cambio, el método `exists()` verifica si existe en el disco (obviamente en memoria si existe la clase). Voy a escribir una respuesta detallando más el tema.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios problemas.

El primero es la ruta de tu archivo. Desconozco si en Android existe la carpeta `/home`, pero estoy seguro que si existe no va a estar accesible para tu aplicación.

Puedes ver con detalle que rutas están accesibles y cómo obtenerlas en [Saving data to a file in your Android application](https://blog.cindypotvin.com/saving-data-to-a-file-in-your-android-application/) (en inglés).

El siguiente problema reside en tu método `escribirDatosContactos()`. Con la programación actual, nunca se escribe realmente el archivo a disco.

Veo que estás confundiendo la creación del objeto `archivo` con la creación del archivo físico en disco, pero son dos cosas distintas.

La instrucción `File archivo = new File(ruta);` no crea nada en el disco. Lo que crea es una instancia de objeto de la clase `File`, que tiene encapsulado el código necesario para interactuar con el sistema de ficheros de la máquina y gestionar un archivo en ella.

Debes valerte de los métodos de esa clase para crear el archivo. De hecho, utilizas el método `exists()`, para verificar que el archivo exista en disco, pero obviamente, si nunca lo has creado, no va a existir, y por tanto nunca entra a ese `if`.

Puedes utilizar el método [`createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) para que el fichero se cree en el disco. Sugiero cambiar tu lógica por algo en la línea de lo siguiente:

```
static void escribirDatosContactos() throws IOException {
   File archivo = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "contactos.txt");
    if(!archivo.exists()) {
      archivo.createNewFile();
    }
    BufferedWriter bw;
    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(ruta);
    ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    out.writeObject(contactos);
    out.close();
    }
}
```

Luego, hay problema también en el método `leerFichContactos()`. En este, no validas la existencia del archivo. La programación asume que el fichero existe y siempre lee su contenido. Obviamente al no existir, va a lanzar un error. Acá nuevamente puedes valerte de [`exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) para evitar este problema. Algo en la línea de:

```
static void leerFichContactos() throws IOException {
   File archivo = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "contactos.txt");
    if archivo.exists() {
        // acá se lee el archivo, pues ya nos aseguramos que existe.
    }
}
```

Comment: He probado a utilizar tu código , pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error en el metodo leerfichContactos(); Concretamente en la linea que dice FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(archivo);

Comment: No había puesto atención a ese método. Si, hay un problema, voy a incluirlo en mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tus respuestas, pero me vuelve a aparecer error en escribirdatoscontacto(); Ahora me aparece No such file or directory en la linea de createnewfile

Comment: Seguramente no existe la ruta.

Comment: Edité la respuesta para añadir código que asegure que existe la ruta.

Comment: ¿Y que ruta debo poner para que no me aparezca dicho error?, el proyecto lo tengo guardado en la carpeta por defecto de android studio

Comment: Ahhh, ¿es android?. Bueno, debes poner una ruta que exista en el dispositivo y accesible a tu aplicación. Por defecto, cada aplicación tiene una serie de rutas pre-definidas para almacenar sus archivos. Si lees inglés, date una vuelta por: https://blog.cindypotvin.com/saving-data-to-a-file-in-your-android-application/

Comment: Por favor, también incluye las etiquetas relevantes en tu pregunta. La ruta "/home/xxxx" no va a existir en android y es algo que pude mencionar desde el inicio.

Comment: Ahora está adaptado para Android. En lo que a mi respecta, hasta aquí llego. No haré más ediciones a la respuesta. Para una próxima, asegurate por favor de incluir toda la información en la pregunta, y de hacer una sola pregunta a la vez.